# Ensure at least one from a group of three checkboxes is checked using jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery Validate plugin on a large form, and have been using the require_from_group method ([after posting previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883017/using-jquery-validate-plugin-to-ensure-at-least-one-of-three-checkboxes-is-check)) to ensure at least one from a group of three checkboxes is checked.

However, I've [ran into an issue](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/412) with this where it stops other rules from working. I've applied a [suggested patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070245/jquery-validator-group-how-to-use-it/13127475#13127475), but that doesn't seem to work correctly either (as mentioned in the above GitHub issue).

So I need to find another way to validate this group of three checkbox fields (note that I need to specifically target this group of three checkboes, as I have other checkbox fields on the form that don't require validating), but I'm not sure where to start with this now. I'm thinking I need to add some sort of custom rule into my jQuery validate code, but I'm not sure where to start with this now so would appreciate some advice, thanks.

Here's my starting HTML (stripped to bare essentials for this question):

```
<form class="my_form" method="post" action="/" >

  <div><ul class="form_errors"></ul></div>

  <label><input class="my_checkbox_group" id="my_checkbox_1" name="my_checkbox_1[]" type="checkbox" value="Yes"> My checkbox 1</label>
  <label><input class="my_checkbox_group" id="my_checkbox_2" name="my_checkbox_2[]" type="checkbox" value="Yes"> My checkbox 2</label>
  <label><input class="my_checkbox_group" id="my_checkbox_3" name="my_checkbox_3[]" type="checkbox" value="Yes"> My checkbox 3</label>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Here's my starting JS (this makes all three of the checkboxes mandatory, but I only want at least one from three to be checked):

```
$(".my_form").validate({
  errorLabelContainer: ".form_errors",
  wrapper: "li",
  rules: {
    'my_checkbox_1[]': { required: true },
    'my_checkbox_2[]': { required: true },
    'my_checkbox_3[]': { required: true }
  },
  messages: {
    'my_checkbox_1[]': "This field is required",
    'my_checkbox_2[]': "This field is required",
    'my_checkbox_3[]': "This field is required"
  }
});
```

**Edit 1:** Sorry, I should have added that the name attributes of each checkbox can't be the same. These names map to specific custom field names in the CMS, so if they were all the same, the values in the fields wouldn't be saved correctly when the form was submitted. This is also the reason why I never followed the second example on the [jQuery Validate demo page](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I wrote a custom method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) that checks to make sure at least one of the three checkboxes is ticked.

It gets the job done *without modifying* any of your `name` or `id` attributes, or adding anything new to the HTML.  (However, you had some invalid HTML that I cleaned up a bit.)

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkboxrule", function (value, element) {
    return ($('#my_checkbox_1').is(':checked') || $('#my_checkbox_2').is(':checked') || $('#my_checkbox_3').is(':checked'));
}, "Select at least one of these three");
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/u4WM4/**

I also used the `groups` option to put the three messages into one.  (You can simply remove it if you want three messages instead.)

The complete jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.validator.addMethod("checkboxrule", function (value, element) {
        return ($('#my_checkbox_1').is(':checked') || $('#my_checkbox_2').is(':checked') || $('#my_checkbox_3').is(':checked'))
    }, "Select at least one of these three");

    $('.my_form').validate({ 
        errorLabelContainer: ".form_errors",
        wrapper: "li",
        groups: {
            somename: "my_checkbox_1[] my_checkbox_2[] my_checkbox_3[]"
        },
        rules: {
            'my_checkbox_1[]': {
                checkboxrule: true
            },
            'my_checkbox_2[]': {
                checkboxrule: true
            },
            'my_checkbox_3[]': {
                checkboxrule: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, Sparky! :) I've just got this working with my actual form and it's working great. I've also used this to add a new custom method for a different group of checkboxes too, so this is a nice and repeatable/flexible solution.

Comment: @Stephen you could trim this down with  return $('.my_checkbox_group:checked').length > 0

Comment: @Sparky For info - I applied your answer to a group of text fields and came up with an issue of the error class not being removed. I posted and got an answer for this in the link below, but I just went back into your fiddle and noticed the same thing happens with the checkboxes there, only it's not noticeable as there's no error styling. So just letting you know out of interest really. Thanks. :) Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245659/jquery-validate-error-class-not-removing-from-field

Comment: @Stephen, I'll have to take a look at that.  Typically, adding & removing the classes is handled by the plugin automatically. Maybe there is a bug when using a custom method.

Comment: @Sparky I've been searching around some more and it seems to be a common issue when using addMethod - maybe something to do with a 'highlight' function in jQuery Validate. I even found a similar thread that you'd contributed to from 2011: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549385/how-to-remove-error-class-using-jquery-validate I don't know enough about JS or jQuery Validate to know whether this is a bug, or whether there should be a standard way of handling this when using addMethod.

Answer (score 2):

Try

**HTML**

You don't have to use different `name array attribute`, it can be used like

```
<label><input class="my_checkbox_group" id="my_checkbox_1" name="my_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="Yes"> My checkbox 1</label>
<label><input class="my_checkbox_group" id="my_checkbox_2" name="my_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="Yes"> My checkbox 2</label>
<label><input class="my_checkbox_group" id="my_checkbox_3" name="my_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="Yes"> My checkbox 3</label>
```

**SCRIPT**

In `validate Plugin`

```
$('.my_form').validate( {
   errorLabelContainer: ".form_errors",
   wrapper: "li",
   rules: {
      "my_checkbox[]": {
          required: true,
          minlength: 1
   },
   messages: {
      'my_checkbox[]': "This field is required"          
   }
});
```

From http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29

In `simple Jquery`

```
var isChecked=false;
$('input.my_checkbox_group').each(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked'))
   {
       isChecked=true;
   }
});
if(isChecked==false)
{
   alert("Please select a group");
}
```

Comment: It can be possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878601/help-with-jquery-validate-plugin-and-checkboxes

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rohan. The name attributes have to be different as they're the individual field names in a CMS - if they all had the same name, then the field would not save to the correct custom field when the form is submitted. So I can only differentiate each checkbox via a class or an ID.

Comment: You can call it by `class name` like 
     `rules: {
        my_checkbox_group: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 1
     },`   
Refer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748346/jquery-validate-plugin-cant-validate-classes

Comment: Thanks for the the clarification on that one - my JS/jQuery is not very good, as you can tell. :-)

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to change name attribute for that. need to set same name for each checkbox.

```
<label><input class="my_checkbox_group" id="my_checkbox_1" name="my_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="Yes"> My checkbox 1</label>
<label><input class="my_checkbox_group" id="my_checkbox_2" name="my_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="Yes"> My checkbox 2</label>
<label><input class="my_checkbox_group" id="my_checkbox_3" name="my_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="Yes"> My checkbox 3</label>
```

**JS CODE**

```
$(".my_form").validate({
  errorLabelContainer: ".form_errors",
  wrapper: "li",
  rules : {
        "my_checkbox[]" : {
            required : true,
            minlength : 1
        }
    },
    messages : {
        "my_checkbox[]" : {
            required : "must have checkbox selected",
            minlength : "atleast 1 checkbox should be checked"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Devang. Unfortunately, the name attributes have to be different as they're the individual field names in a CMS - if they all had the same name, then the field would not save to the correct custom field in the CMS when the form is submitted. So I can only differentiate each checkbox field via a class or an ID.