# jQuery validate error class not removing from field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've a custom method for jQuery validate (based on [Sparky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238958/ensure-at-least-one-from-a-group-of-three-checkboxes-is-checked-using-jquery-val/15240802#15240802) for a related question) that checks to make sure that one from a group of four text fields has a value in it. This works fine, except I've just noticed that even though the error message disappears when a value has been entered in one of the fields, the error class remains in place so the text fields highlighted in the error colour (red background in this example).

Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Thanks.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4WM4/2/) of the issue.

Here's my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $.validator.addMethod("textboxrule", function (value, element) {
      return ($('#my_text_field_1').val() != '' || $('#my_text_field_2').val() != '' || $('#my_text_field_3').val() != '' || $('#my_text_field_4').val() != '')
  }, "Select at least one of these four");

  $('.my_form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
      errorLabelContainer: ".form_errors",
      wrapper: "li",
      groups: {
          somename: "my_text_field_1 my_text_field_2 my_text_field_3 my_text_field_4"
      },
      rules: {
          'my_text_field_1': {
              textboxrule: true
          },
          'my_text_field_2': {
              textboxrule: true
          },
          'my_text_field_3': {
              textboxrule: true
          },
          'my_text_field_4': {
              textboxrule: true
          }
      },
      submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
          alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
          return false; // for demo
      }
  });

});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<form class="my_form" method="post" action="#">
    <div>
        <ul class="form_errors"></ul>
    </div>
    <p>
<label>My text field 1</label>
<input id="my_text_field_1" name="my_text_field_1"  type="text" value="" /></p>

<p>
  <label>My text field 2</label>
  <input id="my_text_field_2" name="my_text_field_2"  type="text" value="" />
</p>

<p>
  <label>My text field 3</label>
  <input id="my_text_field_3" name="my_text_field_3"  type="text" value="" /></p>

<p>
  <label>My text field 3</label>
  <input id="my_text_field_4" name="my_text_field_4"  type="text" value="" /></p>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
input.error { 
    background: red; 
}
```

Comment: For text fields, you should be using [the `require_from_group` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/) from [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js).  Then this additional error message manipulation would have been unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to extend your validation method to remove the error class if it passes validation. Try this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("textboxrule", function (value, element) {
    var returnValue = ($('#my_text_field_1').val() != '' || $('#my_text_field_2').val() != '' || $('#my_text_field_3').val() != '' || $('#my_text_field_4').val() != '');

    if (returnValue) {
        $("#my_text_field_1, #my_text_field_2, #my_text_field_3, #my_text_field_4").removeClass("error");
    }

    return returnValue;
}, "Select at least one of these four");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u4WM4/3/

Comment: Thanks for this Matty. I've applied your answer to my code and it does the job!

Comment: @Stephen No problems, glad I could help!

Comment: You should not be manipulating classes within the rule/method because the plugin already handles all of this automatically.  Besides, the whole thing was unnecessary in the first place because the [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js) contains [the `require_from_group` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/) which fully handles making one or more fields from a group of fields required.